# Postman receiving a callabck message from the server

Tags: postman, asynccallback

I am implementing a server that will receive a POST request from the client, through an API, in the header it has a callback URL where we need to send a PUT message for this callback URL later. This is to implement an Async API.
In resume the flow is:

```
Client ---    POST        ---> Server
Client <--    202          --- Server
Client <-- PUT/CallbackURL --- Server
Client ---     200        ---> Server
```

Can I make Postman having a Stub server capable to receive this callback and do a 200 response?

Comment: Postman has Mock Servers: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @adsc!

> Postman has Mock Servers: learning.postman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock

Your comment fixes my problem and I didn't find it before.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock/